# Cube with different combinations of refl in cubical agda

Tags: agda, cubical-type-theory

I am working on the following lemma but the proof is starting to grow longer, and longer.

```
assoc-lUnit-rUnit-refl-lemma : ∀ {ℓ} → {A : Type ℓ} → {x : A}
           → (assoc refl refl refl) 
              ≡ 
             sym (lUnit (refl {x = x} ∙ refl)) ∙ (rUnit (refl ∙ refl))
```

It refers to definitions in the cubical library in file [GrupoidLaws.agda](https://github.com/agda/cubical/blob/265294a703b821fea92a8cab1589030963dff4e7/Cubical/Foundations/GroupoidLaws.agda)

I do not necessarily expect whole proof here, just some advice. 
Should I expect this proof to be straightforward thanks to refl everywhere?
Or do I have to basically follow back all definitions inside lUnit, rUnit, and assoc,
because refl does not force any computation?